# linked object error: The server application, source file, or item can't be found, or returned an unknown error

Tags: pdf, powerpoint, office365

I linked a pdf as object in powerpoint. For that I wend to insert-> Object and there I select Create from file I select the pdf file and I check Link checkbox.

As soon as I press OK button I get the error I put as title. I try to found what was the error and I found some solutions:

Open the run window and do the following:
1. regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\ole32.dll
2. In the RegSvr32 dialog box, click OK.
3. Restart the computer.

I also saw in some forums that reinstalling the pdf reader that they have the problem used to be solved. But no one of those solutions works for me I still have the same error.

**EDIT**
I test with different type of files and it gives me the same error when I try to make the same process.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the pdf file is open in Adobe Reader. If it is open, close it. Retry the PowerPoint Insert Object operation.

Answer (score -1):

You need to disable protected mode in Adobe Reader.

In reader XI:
Edit > Preferences > Security (Enhanced) > Enable Protected Mode at startup

and remove the checkmark. Close or restart Adobe Reader (make sure there are no processes still running) and try again.